# Unable to execute Maven project in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

Thanks for reading this question. I am very new to Maven and Jenkins and trying to implement it for learning purpose. I am getting the below output in jenkins console. I am well aware that there is a silly mistake but I couldnt find it. Please advice.

```
Parsing POMs
[naukri] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java" -cp C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-agent-1.5.jar;C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MAVEN\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MAVEN/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MAVEN C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.49.jar C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar 52941
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Remote call on Channel to Maven [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java, -cp, C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-agent-1.5.jar;C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MAVEN\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MAVEN/conf/logging, jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main, C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MAVEN, C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.49.jar, C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar, C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar, 52941] failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:760)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache$MavenProcess.call(ProcessCache.java:161)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:840)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:536)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1718)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Failed to load hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$JenkinsEventSpy
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.loadClassFile(RemoteClassLoader.java:325)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:237)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1880)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1610)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:52)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:425)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:413)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:310)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:547)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:185)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:99)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at ......remote call to Channel to Maven [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java, -cp, C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-agent-1.5.jar;C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MAVEN\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MAVEN/conf/logging, jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main, C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MAVEN, C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.49.jar, C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar, C:\Users\Badri\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar, 52941](Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1356)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:221)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:752)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/eventspy/EventSpy : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromParent(ClassRealm.java:445)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:466)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.loadClassFile(RemoteClassLoader.java:323)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:237)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1880)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1610)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:52)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:425)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:413)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:310)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:547)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:185)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:99)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: it's saying a pom.xml is bad. do you reference EventSpy directly in a pom.xml file? if so, apparently version 51.0 is an unsupported version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the error you must use at least JDK 7 in your runtime environment.